# UINavigation Transition Stuttering

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a `UIImagePickerController` which allows the user to take a photo and then I store it in a `UIImageView` as follows:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.photoImageView.image = nil;
    [self.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^
    {
        UIImage *image = [[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] retain];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            self.photoImageView.image = image;
            [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
            self.rightButton.enabled = YES;
            [image release];
        });

    });
}
```

When I pass this image as a parameter to the next `UIViewController` that gets pushed on the navigation stack, the `UINavigation` transition stutters and is real choppy / ugly. I've done a profile and nothing in my code is really standing out.

I get it that the photo taken with the camera might be big, but if I'm just passing a reference to it, why should that have an effect on anything? I have photos that I've taken in my photo library, and when I select them from there and pass them to the next transition, everything is smooth.

Anyone have any insight into what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the resizing process takes place when the new UIViewController being pushed to the navigation stack.

Let's say the photo taken from the iPhone 4 camera has 2592 x 1936 resolution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270202/what-is-resolution-of-photo-taken-by-iphone-4-camera). Your UIImageView has 400 x 300px size, then the resize process will take place in the viewWillAppear which might make your transition stutters.

Several workaround for this:

1. Display the image in viewDidAppear, just keep the reference to the image and set it to the imageView.image in the viewDidAppear.
2. Resize the picture, let's say to 640 x 960, first before displaying it.

Comment: Thanks, you know I had just come upon this: http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2010/08/uiimagepickercontroller/ which describes exactly what you're talking about with the resizing. My question to you is, what bit of code can I call to determine the correct size to resize the image in? Should it simply be the portrait screen bounds (*2 if there is retina?)

Comment: correct size to resize is determined by the UIImageView size itself and the aspect ratio you want to have (aspect fit, aspect fill, etc).

I'm suggessting the 640 * 960 because that's the retina resolution of the screen (not for iPhone 5 though), and hoping it'll be small enough to make the transition stutters disappear.

That resolution will also works if you want to save a resized version to the camera roll library (which will be showing the full screen photo).

Comment: For me I'm scaling that image in the imageView so I guess the screen size will do it. Do you mind putting that link in the answer for #2?

Comment: here's a good blog post explaining about resizing image in iOS, http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/, hope that help